# Xquery traverse tree

Tags: xquery, traversal

i am new to xquery. I have the following xml document :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <lines>
        <line>
            <id>1</id>
            <par>1</par>
        </line>
        <line>
            <id>2</id>
            <par>1</par>
        </line>
        <line>
            <id>3</id>
            <par>2</par>
        </line>
        <line>
            <id>4</id>
            <par>2</par>
        </line>
        <line>
            <id>5</id>
            <par>1</par>
        </line>
        <line>
            <id>6</id>
            <par>5</par>
        </line>
        <line>
            <id>7</id>
            <par>5</par>
        </line>
        <line>
            <id>8</id>
            <par>5</par>
        </line>
    </lines>
```

I would like to create a function that would get as input a certain id , and would return all the line elements - descendants of this id , including the one given as input. For example giving as input 1 it would return the line elements with ids 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8. I know i can go to depth 1 using the following: `lines/line[par=id_given]`, but what if i would like to fetch all descendants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define a function which traverses the tree recursively. This one does works level-wise:

```
declare function local:traverse($tree as element(lines), $id as xs:integer*) as element(line)* {
 let $level := $tree//line[par=$id][id!=$id]
 return
  if ($level)
  then ($level, local:traverse($tree, $level/id))
  else ()
};
```

You can call it using `local:traverse(/lines, 0)`.

But this function will not deal with your example XML, as this is no tree: there is a cycle in the root element which isn't allowed. You will have to introduce some new unique root id or remove the parent from the root for having a real tree.

```
<lines>
    <line>
        <id>1</id>
        <par>0</par>
    </line>
    [snip]
```

You could also change the code above to be able to deal with these self-references: Add the predicate `[id!=$id]` to the end of the definition of `$level`, this will exclude self-references. Now your root node is excluded from the results, reinclude it in the function call: `(/lines/line[id=1], local:traverse(/lines, 1))`.

Comment: The ids are only for the purpose of the example so the second option , is not valid. The par element in my case represents the parent node. So given an id i would like to get all the nodes below that. For example for input 1, i would like to get all the nodes for input  2 i would like to get 2,3,4 and for input 5 ->5,6,7,8

Comment: Sorry, missunderstood your question. I redefined my answer.